# Declare a function that doesn't return in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to declare a "no return" function in Scala? I.e.

```
def abort(): ! = {
    System.exit(1);
}
```

(The `!` in this example is taken from Rust, and it means: entering this function is a one-way trip and we'll never return from it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Nothing](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/Nothing.html):

```
def loop: Nothing = loop
```

Expressions of this type cannot return normally, but can go into infinite loops or throw exceptions. However, you can't use Nothing in your example, since System.exit has a signature saying it returns Unit. Instead, you could try something like this to make the compiler happy:

```
def abort(): Nothing = {
  System.exit(1);
  ???  // Unreachable
}
```

Comment: You can use `sys.exit()` though. :)

Answer (score 11):

This is exactly what the `Nothing` type represents—a method or expression that will never return a value. It's the type of an expression that throws an exception, for example:

```
scala> :type throw new Exception()
Nothing
```

Scala also provides a special `???` operator with this type, which is commonly used to get code to typecheck during development.

```
scala> :type ???
Nothing
```

`Nothing` is a subtype of everything else, so you can use an expression of type `Nothing` anywhere any type is expected.

Answer (score 3):

Some real world example:

```scala
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import zio._

object Server extends App {
  val program: ZIO[Any, Throwable, Nothing] =
    UIO(ActorSystem()).bracket(terminateSystem) { implicit system =>
      implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
      for {
        _ <- IO.fromFuture { _ =>
          Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "localhost", 8080)
        }
        _ <- IO.never
      } yield ()
    }

  def run(args: List[String]) = program.fold(_ => 1, _ => 0)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nothing, its primary usage is to signal termination.(Scala official documentation https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Nothing.html.)
Normally nothing doesn't returns anything not even computation and used for methods which continuously throws exception.